# Counting number of occurrences of a keyword using Flashtext in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have a dataset of youtube videos and it includes their descriptions. For each video I would like to add a column that shows how many times the string "bit.ly" occurs. I can get the keyword finder to work, but I cannot format the results into a single list that I could put back into the data frame for analysis.

Here's my code:

```
from flashtext import KeywordProcessor
keyword=KeywordProcessor()
dictionary = {
    "http://": ['http://'],
    "bit.ly": ['bit.ly']
}

keyword.add_keywords_from_dict(dictionary)

test_column = X_train['description']
list_of_descriptions = test_column.values.T.tolist()
for i in list_of_descriptions:
    global_list = []
    words=[]
    words.append(keyword.extract_keywords(i))
    print(words)
```

[screenshot of my code / results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uu2Z.png)

So, I would like that output of print(words) to be formatted into a list. If I add a line like global_list.append(words) right under the print words line, it does not work correctly. I would think this would work because if I put print('test') inside the for loop, it prints 'test' the correct number of times, showing that the program runs through the a bunch of times. I don't know why I can't get the variable 'words' to append to this list every time it goes through the loop. I would like to have a list with the number of occurrences of the term 'bit.ly' for each row in the data set.

Thanks.

Comment: Each time you loop, you set words to an empty array. you should put words=[] before the for loop

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
from flashtext import KeywordProcessor
keyword=KeywordProcessor()
dictionary = {
    "http://": ['http://'],
    "bit.ly": ['bit.ly']
}

keyword.add_keywords_from_dict(dictionary)

#test_column = X_train['description']
# Fake data
list_of_descriptions = ['bit.ly bit.ly', 'lol http://', 'I love pizza', 'bit.ly']#test_column.values.T.tolist()

words=[]
for i in list_of_descriptions:
    words.append(len(keyword.extract_keywords(i)))
```

or using list comprhension:

```
words = [len(keyword.extract_keywords(i)) for i in list_of_descriptions]
```

in both cases `words` contains:

```
# [2, 1, 0, 1]
```

If you want to know the different values ​​of each occurrence, you can do this:

```
[{k: l.split().count(k) for k in dictionary} for l in list_of_descriptions]

[{'http://': 0, 'bit.ly': 2},
 {'http://': 1, 'bit.ly': 0},
 {'http://': 0, 'bit.ly': 0},
 {'http://': 0, 'bit.ly': 1}]
```

if instead you want to count the occurrences of all the words in each sentence:

```
from collections import Counter

[Counter(i.split()) for i in list_of_descriptions]

[Counter({'bit.ly': 2}),
 Counter({'lol': 1, 'http://': 1}),
 Counter({'I': 1, 'love': 1, 'pizza': 1}),
 Counter({'bit.ly': 1})]
```